# Why recursion function comes before the swap-function here?

Tags: c, arrays, function, sorting, recursion

I wonder about the recursion here in the rearrangement function, the recursion here is to sort the array by a given number(x), the small than-X elements sorted in the beginning & the greater than-X sorted at the end of the array. but as you can see in the last two lines, is it important to put the recursion before swap? & what happened if putting the recursion after the swap? does it must-to-do always to put the recursion before?

```
void rearrange(int a[], int n, int x) {
    if (n == 0)
        return;
    if (a[0] <= x)
        rearrange(a + 1, n - 1, x);
    else {
        if (a[n - 1] > x)
            rearrange(a, n - 1, x);
        else {
            rearrange(a + 1, n - 2, x);
            swap(a, a + n - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Something that really really helps me with recursion and code in general is to trace it on paper

Comment: It depends on the algorithm.

Comment: (a) Yes, it's important. (b) Did you try it? (c) depends on the algorithm.

Comment: I agree with what @Katianie says, get a paper, write down what you expect and what is happening, maybe use some prints :)

Comment: Just to demonstrate. Try [this](https://ideone.com/T8Udo8)

Comment: Consider: in the alternative that the swap is performed at all, does the recursive call that accompanies it directly or indirectly modify the array elements to be swapped?

Comment: It swaps the first and last.. The recursion passes the pointer  `a + 1` with length `n-2` so the two lines will affect different memory locations. Switching the order might make it tail recursive in gcc.